# Why is LINQ to SQL converting my string parameter to a column name?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

This Linq to SQL query ...

```
    Return (From t In Db.Concessions Where t.Country = "ga" Select t.ConcessionID, t.Title, t.Country)
```

... is generating this SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ConcessionID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Country]
FROM [dbo].[Concessions] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Country] = ga
```

... when what I want is

```
WHERE [t0].[Country] = 'ga'
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The Country field was a char(2); I changed it to nvarchar(50), and that fixed the problem.   Is this a bug in Linq to SQL?

Comment: In VB, do you need to use single quotes with Chars, like in C# maybe? As in Country = 'GA' ?

Comment: @AugustLights: No, that's not the case in VB

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess.... could it be?

`t.Country = "ga"`

vs.

`t.Country == "ga"`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it shouldn't be generating either of those.  It would convert the constant into a parameter, so it would be:

```
SELECT [t0].[ConcessionID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Country]
FROM [dbo].[Concessions] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Country] = @p0
```

with @p0 passed as 'ga'.
could that be that you are seeing?

Comment: Nope, I copied and pasted the execution SQL straight from the debugger in VS.

Comment: I've just duplicated your query as closely as I could, use the Northwind database and LINQPad.  It produced the correct SQL.  My only suggestion is that there must be something screwy with either the database itself, or the DataContext created from it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure about this particular example, but there is a known bug that causes similar problems with nvarchar(1) fields. It may be related.

There is a [bug report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=337188&wa=wsignin1.0) about it and I also [wrote about it](http://reddnet.net/code/linq-to-sql-bug-quot-system-formatexception-string-must-be-exactly-one-character-long-quot/) on my own site too.

Answer (score -1):

the select should be

```
Select New With {t.ConcessionID, t.Title, t.Country}
```

rather than

```
Select t.ConcessionID, t.Title, t.Country
```

you need to create a new instance of an anonymous type to contain the fields.

Comment: No, it still is generating the exact same SQL.

Comment: Only other thing I have is double check Concession.Country is of the correct type in both VB and in the database.

Comment: It was of the correct type - char(2) - but changing it to nvarchar(50) fixed the problem. Strange.